# Deduce that $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}(p-1)-k}$

Tags: prime-numbers, legendre-symbol

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Consider the numbers $$2 \cdot 1,2 \cdot 2,\dots,2\cdot \frac{1}{2}(p-1) $$

and let  $k$ be the largest integer that satsifies $$2k \le \frac{1}{2}(p-1)$$

Prove that if $l \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfies $k \lt l \lt \frac{1}{2}(p-1)$ then $2l-p$ is negative and is the least residue of $2l$. Deduce that $$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}(p-1)-k}$$

I feel like i need to use Gauss' lemma but i'm not sure how i would show that the number of numbers with negative least residue is equal to $\frac{1}{2}(p-1)-k$

Comment: Do you know about the [lemma of Gauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(number_theory))?

Comment: Yes i am aware of the lemma. I am struggling to show that the number of numbers with negative least residue is equal to $\frac{1}{2}(p-1)-k$ as i feel this would be sufficient alongside Gauss' Lemma

Comment: Can you show that for $m\gt k$, we have $2m\gt\frac p2$ ?

Comment: Notice that the integer after $\dfrac{p-1}2$ is $\dfrac{p+1}2$ which is $\gt\dfrac p2$

Comment: Also, there are exactly $\dfrac{p-1}2$ quadratic residues modulo odd prime $p$

Comment: So there would be $k$ positive quadratic residues modulo $p$?

Comment: .... that are $\leq\dfrac p2$. Now, apply Gauss' lemma.

Comment: I'm unsure how I would give proper mathematical justification using the $l \in \mathbb{Z}$ that satisfies $k<l<\frac{1}{2}(p-1)$

Comment: I do not intend to discuss this in chat but rather that you do some thinking of your own and edit your post to include some proper attempts for the stated problem. Try to use the hints in my comments to come up with a proper proof.